# Backbone.history.navigate with $(window).on("hashchange") strange behavior

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, local-storage, hashchange

I have a Rails app that I'm using with Backbone JS as a FE framework with Coffeescript syntax. Now to get to the point quickly I'm using a Backbone trick than replaces Rails's `redirect_to` method:

```
redirectTo = (something) ->
  Backbone.history.navigate('')
  Bacbkone.history.navigate("##{something}", {trigger: true})
```

And whenever I need a full refresh to my page for example when I'm creating something I use it(this is maybe a wrong approach but I'm new to Backbone). Now I also use localStorage["something"] to store values that I'll use for later. I also have a function:

```
$(window).on 'hashchange', ->
    window.localStorage.clear()
```

Here is the strange part. For example I redirect to a #products page with `redirectTo('products')` by some logic the localStorage needs to be cleared and I should not be able to use his values in the Router. But the funny part is I can cause it first goes to the action `'#products'` from the Backbone Router and then triggers the `$(window).on('hashchange')`. Any clues how can this happen and if this is something regular?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points.
 1. To make a complete refresh of page you can do

```
window.location.reload();
```

2. `$(window).on 'hashchange'` handler will fire whenever the hash part of URL on page changes.

What could be going wrong ?:
I see already you are clearing localstorage on hashChange, but this hashChange handler will fire after the route has made transition to products page.

So whats the solution : ?
Quick way is to clear the localstorage when you do `redirectTo('products');`

for example

```
//some code 

redirectTo('products');
window.localStorage.clear();

//Some more code
```

By this way you will never have localStorage cleared.

Hope that helps.
Thanks